# Port Address Forwarding / Nat Function In Python 3.7

Tags: python, sockets, networking, firewall

I'm currently coding a firewall in python. 
This firewall must be able to tell from a whitelist if a stream is allowed to pass.

The purpose of the firewall is to request it on the right port to get the requested service. 
For example if you want to access a web server behind this firewall, you just have to request the firewall on port 80 or 443, the firewall will forward the packets to the right machine according to the whitelist. Everything must be transparent for the user

Currently to work on this subject I use scapy to sniff the packets and transmit them. 
But for a simple HTTP communication (in TCP) nothing works, same for UDP and ICMP.

I think my problem comes from the fact that I use scapy to sniff packets and retransmit them and that I don't use threads. 
I would like to know if someone has already done something similar and if you have any advice on which modules to use.

I'll try to detail my code as much as I can to give you an idea of how it works.

First you have the main(), this function sniffs the packets and determines whether the packet comes from the outside or the inside.
According to these parameters it determines to which other function to send the packet to be processed.

```
def main():

    test = 0
    buffer = []

    # INFINITE LOOPS FOR THE MOMENT #
    while(test<1000):

        # SNIFFING PACKET ON THE EXTERNAL AND INTERNAL INTERFACE #
        packet = sniff(filter="ip",iface=["ens192","InternalInterface"],count=1)

        if(packet):

            PacketContent = packet[0]
            IpDestination = PacketContent[IP].dst
            IpDestination = str(IpDestination)
            IPSource = PacketContent[IP].src
            IPSource = str(IPSource)

    # GETTING THE IP AND MASK OF THE INBOUND PACKET #
            LocalIp = ipaddress.ip_network(IfIp+"/"+Mask,strict = False)
            NetworkIp = ipaddress.ip_network(IpDestination+"/"+Mask,strict = False)

    # GETTING THE IP AND MASK OF THE EXTERNAL NETWORK INTERFACE OF THE FIREWALL #
            IfIp = ni.ifaddresses('ens192')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
            Mask = ni.ifaddresses('ens192')[ni.AF_INET][0]['netmask']

    # GETTING THE IP AND MASK OF THE INTERNAL NETWORK INTERFACE OF THE FIREWALL #
            IfIp2 = ni.ifaddresses('InternalInterface')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
            Mask2 = ni.ifaddresses('InternalInterface')[ni.AF_INET][0]['netmask']

    # GETTING THE NETWORK IP OF PACKET AND OF INTERNAL INTERFACE #
            LocalIp2 = ipaddress.ip_network(IfIp2+"/"+Mask2,strict = False)
            IPSource = ipaddress.ip_network(IPSource+"/"+Mask,strict = False)

    # IF A PACKET IS DESTINATED FOR THE ADDRESS OF THE EXTERNAL FIREWALL INTERFACES #
            if(IfIp == IpDestination):
                if(PacketContent[TCP].dport == 22):
                    main()
                print("Forwarding "+ IpDestination + " to IN")
                buffer =  ForwardingPort(PacketContent,buffer)

    # IF A PACKET IS DESTINATED FOR THE ADDRESS OF THE INTERNAL FIREWALL INTERFACES #
            elif(IPSource == LocalIp2):
                PacketContent.show()
                print("Forwarding  "+ str(IPSource) + " to OUT")
                buffer = BufferPort(PacketContent,buffer)
```

Then if the packet come from outside the function ForwardingPort will be call
this function takes as argument the received packet as well as the array containing the lists of the temporary ports of the clients

```
def ForwardingPort(Packet,buffer):

    # IF THE PACKET TYPE IS 6 IT'S TCP #
    elif(Packet[IP].proto == 6):

        # GETTING THE ASKED SOCKET NUMBER #
        Service = Packet[TCP].dport
        Service = str(Service)

        # OPENING THE FILES THAT CONTAINS SOCKET FORWARDING RULES #
        f = open("/root/ProjetMarsan/Forwading.txt")

        # READING EACH LINE TO FIND THE ASKED SOCKET #

        for li in f.readlines() :

            # IF THE PORT IS AUTHORIZED ON THE FILE #
            if Service in li:

                # GETTING DESTINATION SERVER IP ON THE INTERNAL NETWORK #
                ipDestNat = li.split('=')[1]
                ipDestNat = ipDestNat.replace(" ","")
                ipDestNat = ipDestNat.replace("\n","")

                # REPLACEMENT OF THE ORIGINAL IP WITH THE IP OF THE CORRECT MACHINE CONTAINED IN THE TEXT FILE #
                Packet[IP].dst = ipDestNat

                # BACKUP OF THE TEMPORARY PORT OPENED BY THE CLIENT TO INTEROGATE THE FIREWALL IN A TEXT FILE #
                IpSrcBuff = str(Packet[IP].src)
                SPortBuff = str(Packet[IP].sport)
                buffer.append(SPortBuff + ":" + IpSrcBuff)

                # RECALCULATION OF THE NEW CHECKSUM #
                del Packet[IP].chksum
                del Packet[TCP].chksum
                Packet.show2()

                # SENDING THE PACKET ON THE INTERNAL INTERFACES TO THE RIGHT SERVER #
                sendp(Packet,iface="InternalInterface")

                # RETURNING THE LIST OF THE TEMPORARY PORT OF CLIENT #
                return(buffer)
```

Now if a packet come from the inside of the firewall the function BufferPort will be call.

```
def BufferPort(Packet,buffer):

    # GETTING THE PORT DESTINATION OF THE PACKET #
    Dport = str(Packet[IP].dport)

    # CHECKING IF THE TEMPORARY SOCKET IS ON THE BUFFER LIST #
    for yo in buffer:

        print("checking buffer")
        lo = lo + 1

        # IF THE TEMPORARY SOCKET IS IN, REPLACE IP BY THE EXTERNAL FIREWALL INTERFACE IP AND RECALCULATE PACKET CHECKSUM #
        if(Dport in yo):

            ipDestBuff = yo.split(":")[1]
            ipDestBuff = ipDestBuff.replace(" ","")
            ipDestBuff = ipDestBuff.replace("\n","")

            Packet[IP].dst = ipDestBuff
            Packet[IP].src = "192.168.1.81"

            del Packet[IP].chksum
            del Packet[TCP].chksum
            Packet.show2()

            sendp(Packet,iface="ens192")
            buffer[lo] = ""
    return buffer
```

Thank You.

Comment: Not having a hardware assist for this type of thing is going to greatly slow the throughput.

Comment: It's a little personal project. So I don't push vice that far :)